# send email via telnet ruby script

Tags: ruby, telnet

I'm new with ruby and need to send an email via telnet using a relay host with no authentication. I can do it with a linux shell but I need to put it in a script so I can "simplify" its use, I know it's not the best way but I can't find other since the server where i'm working on it's severely restricted and limited.

```
require 'net/telnet.rb'

mail = Net::Telnet::new(
     "Host"       => "domain.ip",  # default: "localhost"
     "Port"       => 25,           # default: 23
     "Output_log" => "output_log", # default: nil (no output)
     "Dump_log"   => "dump_log",   # default: nil (no output)
     "Prompt"     => /[$%#>] \z/n, # default: /[$%#>] \z/n
     "Telnetmode" => true,         # default: true
     "Timeout"    => 10,           # default: 10
     "Waittime"   => 0,            # default: 0
   )

mail.cmd('helo MYDOMAIN'){ |c| print c }
mail.cmd('mail from: test@domain.com')
mail.cmd('rcpt to: test2@domain.com')
mail.cmd('data')
mail.cmd("subject: test cmd \n\n mensaje de prueba\n\n")
mail.cmd(".\n")
mail.close
```

I found the `net/telnet.rb` ruby class and this is my try... after `mail.cmd('helo MYDOMAIN')` I can't keep writing other commands, what I get is:

```
220 mail.server.com ESMTP
250 mail.server.com
```

After this I'm suposed to write `mail from`, etc. to create the mail. But I can't in the ruby script. I have try using:

```
mail.puts('mail from: test...')
mail.write('mail from: test...')
mail.print('mail from: test...')
mail.cmd('mail from: test...')
```

As written in [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/Net/Telnet.html)

Also I don't get the `telnetmode(true|false)` command maybe you could explain it to me please.

-- Edit --

Shell code trying to emulate:

```
telnet domain.ip 25
#=> Trying domain.ip...
#=> Connected to domain.ip.
#=> Escape character is '^]'.
#=> 220 mail.server.com ESMTP
helo MYDOMAIN
#=>250 mail.server.com
mail from:test@mydomain.com
#=> 250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:test2@mydomain.com
#=> 250 2.1.0 Ok
data
#=> 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
subject: test mail

test mail body

.
#=> 250 2.0.0 =k: queued as B6F08480D12
quit
#=> 221 2.0.0 Bye
#=> Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: What's the linux shell code you're trying to emulate? (Does the shell version work?)

Comment: @TomLord I've updated the post with the shell code and yes, it works, I have send some emails with it to my personal account and works fine.

Comment: Is it a strict requirement that you use telnet? Using http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html will turn your "difficult to maintain" script into something that is much easier to maintain. Even for someone who is completely new to Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of the user ddubs how suggest the `net\smtp` gem (One that I didn't know) I was able to create a simple mail sender and using the `mailfactory` gem

> Is it a strict requirement that you use telnet? Using ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/Net/SMTP.html will turn your "difficult to maintain" script into something that is much easier to maintain. Even for someone who is completely new to Ruby. – ddubs

Here is the code sample

```
require 'net/smtp'
require 'mailfactory'

mail_body_HTML = '<h1> mail title</h1> your text in <b>HTML</b>'    
mail_body_PLAIN = 'this is plain text'
mail_subject = 'test email'     
mail_from = 'noreply@mydomain.com'
mail_to = 'user@otherdomain.com'
# mail_filePath = ''

mail = MailFactory.new()
mail.to = mail_to
mail.from = mail_from
mail.subject = mail_subject
mail.html = mail_body_HTML
# mail.text = mail_body_PLAIN
# mail.attach(mail_filePath)

relay_ip = x.x.x.x

Net::SMTP.start(relay_ip,25) do |smtp|
   smtp.send_message(mail.to_s, mail_from, mail_to)
end
```

Comment: Glad you got it working! You can also shrink this down by directly assigning the strings to the mail object (instead of initializing all those vars)

Comment: Yes, I'll do that but I wrote it this way for educational purpouse. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The telnet protocol is really, really rudimentary which is why the `telnet` command is useful for testing TCP/IP based services such as SMTP or HTTP. It does not mean those services actually use the telnet protocol, as they don't. They're conveniently plain-text in nature which means it's practical to use `telnet` for simple tests.

You should **not** be using the Telnet module for anything other than connecting to telnet services, though given it's 2017 it's unlikely you'll find any of those around.

You **should** be using something like [Socket](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html) to connect. This can create a bare TCP/IP connection with full control over sending. As this is a wrapper around a regular POSIX filehandle you can use all the IO methods on it for reading, writing, and other control functions, like a proper socket `shutdown`.

Writing an SMTP adapter is not as easy as it seems, there's a lot of tricky things to tackle with regard to IO. You'll need to use `IO.select` to properly test for new data, plus that the socket is clear to write your email.

Here's a new stub:

```
require 'socket'

mail = TCPSocket.new("smtp.example.com", 25)

mail.write("HELO example.com\r\n")
```

Another note is that when you call `require` you should never specify the file extension. It's always handled for you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but lead me to explore other ways, thanks you ^^

Comment: Writing an SMTP client from scratch is a bit above and beyond the five minutes I can spend answering a question here, but hopefully this sets you on the right direction. If you're looking to learn the fundamentals, [this book](http://www.unpbook.com) is a good primer on the basics.